# How do you alert user if a certain piece of text is present within HTML document using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, search, alert

So when the web page loads, I want to implement a script that will alert the user that a specific piece of text is present within the HTML document. I want this script to search the whole document for that specified text and if the text is present, trigger an alert. If no specified text is present, then do nothing. I'm not really good at functions like this and couldn't find answers on how to search a html document on specific lines of text using javascript.

Comment: document.body.innerText

Comment: So window onload, read the document's text. Look for the string (match, indexOf, etc).... Seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: yea but whats the properties i need to use in order to accomplish this? I'm not too familiar with javascript and its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Content">
    <div id="Panes"><div>
        <h2>This is an example</h2>
        <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Nunc ante mauris, sollicitudin vel luctus ac, rhoncus eu est.
            Sed fermentum est non pharetra viverra. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
            Curabitur interdum metus non laoreet vehicula. Aliquam in lorem quis velit accumsan viverra.
            Sed faucibus interdum augue non feugiat. Aliquam libero odio, malesuada aliquam sapien at, varius lobortis quam.
            Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
            Nullam vestibulum ultricies magna sit amet ultricies. Ut a nibh sodales, fringilla ipsum et, dapibus tortor.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var textYouWantToFind = "Lorem Ipsum";
    var textExists = !!document.body.innerText.indexOf(textYouWantToFind);

    if (textExists) {
        alert("We have found " + textYouWantToFind + " !")
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I leave you my answer but with jQuery if you need it:
(Following Daniel's HTML structure)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var txtToFind = 'Lorem ipsum';
    var txtFilter = $('#Content:contains("' + txtToFind + '")').filter(function() {
        alert('Found Text: ' + txtToFind);
    });
});
</script>
```